# How Do I Parse XML for Multiple Attributes?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, attributes, nsdictionary

heightI'm a noob to iphone development and I am trying to parse an xml with elements that contain multiple attributes.  I have several tutorials on parsing XML, but none of them show the steps to parse an element with multiple attributes.  I am trying to parse the xml with NSXMLParser. I want to parse the first occurrence of the media:thumbnail element for the value of the second attribute.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE:

//XML

```
<item>
   <title>March 15 AM Metals Commentary: Eric Zuccarelli</title>
   <link>http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid1683318714001/bclid1644543007001/bctid2228319176001?src=mrss</link>
   <description>Eric Zuccarelli, Independent Copper Trader</description>
   <guid>http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid1683318714001/bclid1644543007001/bctid2228319176001?src=mrss</guid>
   <pubDate>Fri, 15 Mar 2013 06:40:38 -0700</pubDate>
   <media:player height="546" url="http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid1683318714001/bclid1644543007001/bctid2228319176001?src=mrss" width="966" / >
   <media:keywords>commentary,CME Group,financial products,cmedaily,nymex,metals,youtube,Market Commentary,Zuccarelli</media:keywords>
   <media:thumbnail height="90" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d21/unsecured/media/49919183001/49919183001_2228333209001_th-514324d6e4b02e906f7476ba-806787304001.jpg?pubId=49919183001" width="120" / >
   <media:thumbnail height="360" url="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d21/unsecured/media/49919183001/49919183001_2228333208001_vs-514324d6e4b02e906f7476ba-806787304001.jpg?pubId=49919183001" width="480" / >
   <media:category>Metals</media:category>
   <bc:playerid>1683318714001</bc:playerid>
   <bc:lineupid>1644543007001</bc:lineupid>
   <bc:titleid>2228319176001</bc:titleid>
   <bc:duration>215</bc:duration>
   <dcterms:valid / >
   <bc:accountid>49919183001</bc:accountid>
</item>
```

My code is as follws:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentBright = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]){
            if([attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"]==90){
                currentBright = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
                NSLog(@"Brightcove Url:%@", currentBright);  //<--Not reaching this point.
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]&&[attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"]==90){
    currentBright = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"         
    NSLog(@"Brightcove Url:%@", currentBright);
}
```

Comment: Which element you're talking about?

Comment: I am trying to parse the first occurrence of <media:thumbnail> for its url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tryout this....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {          

  currentElement = [elementName copy];
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentBright = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
    if([attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"]==90) {
         currentBright = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
         NSLog(@"Brightcove Url:%@", currentBright); 
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That had me baffled for the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

You're never going to hit your second or third conditional because how can elementName have changed without being advanced? Instead you should un-nest your conditionals.

Right now what happens is:

-didStartTag

ElementName = item -> first condtional hit -> fails second

-didStartTag

ElementName = title -> fails first conditonal

etc....

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I still can't make it work.  Please check my edit.

Comment: You're checking for 90? Shouldn't you be checking for "height"?

Comment: I would set a break point at that line and see the values its checking. You might want to use isEqualToString instead of == on the attribute. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.